# Discrete Maths: I'm not familiar with this notation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

I've the following relation:

$(x,y) \in A \times B, x S y ↔ 2|(x-y)$

What does $2|(x-y)$ mean?

Thank you.

Comment: It means that $2$ divides $(x-y)$.

Comment: ... which, if $x$ and $y$ are integers, means they have the same parity, i.e. they are both odd or both even

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means 2 divides $(x-y)$.

Which is to say that there is an integer $c$ such that $2c = (x-y)$